# What is the /ū/ sound in English symbol?

Tags: pronunciation

In the [American Accent Training](http://www.americanaccent.com/), it shows /ū/ (a line over `u`) is a tense vowel, and takes "smooth" as an example.

However, according to Merriam-Webster dictionary, it should be [ˈsmüt͟h], and there is no any /ū/.

What is /ū/ on earth?

Comment: Different sources use different symbols. To decipher transcriptions in dictionaries, you need to look at a key.

Comment: If you know what "smooth" sounds like, then you just need to go by that, and forget Merriam-Webster when you're working with your American Accent Training materials.  // Take a look at English Language Learners.  Very helpful site.

Comment: Any accent training system that is not using IPA is a waste of time.

Comment: @Cascabel I don't think so. Popular phonetic symbols, e.g., KK and DJ, are based on IPA, but not IPA. One more example, the phonetic symbol of Merriam-Webster dictionary is totally different from IPA.

Comment: @chenzhongpu What?! KK and DJ *are* IPA. Or rather there's no single "*the* IPA". All transcriptions in IPA are by definition applications of IPA. See [IPA Handbook, p. 30](https://books.google.com/books?id=33BSkFV_8PEC&pg=PA30), particularly the last sentence.

Comment: See what the IPA sound in smooth is here: https://tophonetics.com/

Answer (score 6):

Different publications use different conventions. If said book uses "ū" to mean the vowel in *smooth*, i.e. /uː/ or /u/ in IPA-based conventions, and \ü\ in Merriam-Webster, then it is. You can never expect a symbol in one source to represent the same thing in another.

Traditionally, though, "a", "e", "i", "o", or "u" with a macron above it meant "the sound of the name of the letter" in dictionaries from the 18th and 19th centuries. So "ū" in those old dictionaries corresponds to /juː/ or /ju/ in modern IPA conventions, and \yü\ in Merriam-Webster. But not "ū" in your book.